# How to pass a variable from jQuery draggable to droppable

Tags: jquery, variables, draggable, droppable

I am trying to use jQuery draggable/droppable to drag a list item to a div, upon which the list item will be deleted from the draggable ul and an ajax call will be made to delete the corresponding item in a MySQL database.

The HTML:

```
<ul id="draggable">
 <li id="list_1">List item 1</li> // Incrementing ID nos. from database
 <li id="list_2">List item 2</li>
 <li id="list_3">List item 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="droppable"></div>
```

The jQuery so far:

```
$('#draggable li').draggable({
 drag: function(event, ui) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').split("_");
  id = id[1];    // OK so far - but how to pass this to droppable?
  }
});

$('#droppable').droppable({
 drop: function(event, ui) {
  // How to get the id from draggable here so the correct list item is acted on?
  $('#draggable li').remove();
  $.ajax({ 
   url: "delete.php",
   type: "GET",
   data: {
    'id': id,
    'user_id': user_id  // user_id comes from PHP
  }, // end ajax        }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Many thanks for the responses. I got it to work using:

```
<script>
 var user_id = "<?php print($user_id); ?>";

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#draggable li').draggable({
      helper: 'clone'
    });

    $('#droppable').droppable({
      accept: '#draggable li', 
       drop: function(ev, ui) {
         var id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id').split("_");
         var movie_id = id[1];
         $('#draggable li#list_' + id).remove();

         $.ajax({ // begin add ajax
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: { // begin add data
              'id': id,
               'user_id': user_id
            } // end data
         }); // end ajax

       } // end drop function
    }); // end droppable
 }); // end ready

</script>
```

It seeems OK to me - are there any problems with that which you can see?

Comment: Just that you are not waiting an answer by your server in your ajax request, but the Drag & Drop seems to works !
You could probably manage the remove easier than by reselecting the HTML DOM element, but anyway, it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the dragged element using using `ui.draggable.attr('id')` inside your drop function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3TpU/)

[See Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)

Answer (score 3):

You should not manage anything in your "drag" callback for many reasons:

- Because it's triggered at every "move" event, so you are updating your "id" var in a useless way
- Because you can access your element in the "drop" callback easily

Watch the updated JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nVx7a/23/

HTML:

```
<ul id="draggable">
    <li id="list_1" data-id='1'>List item 1</li>
    <li id="list_2" data-id='2'>List item 2</li>
    <li id="list_3" data-id='3'>List item 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="droppable"></div>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#draggable li').draggable();

    $('#droppable').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $element = $(event.toElement), // equivalent to $(ui.helper);
                id = $element.data('id'), // HTML5 way, equivalent to $element.attr('data-id');
                // id = $(this).attr('id').split("_"); // HTML4 way
                $YOUR_PHP_VAR = 1;

            console.log($element, id, $YOUR_PHP_VAR);
            // Lock the UI, display a loader or something...

            $.ajax({ 
                url: "delete.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    'id': id,
                    'user_id': $YOUR_PHP_VAR  // user_id comes from PHP
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                console.log('success', response);
                // Once your Database request is successfully executed, remove the element from your UI.
                $element.remove();
            }).fail(function (response) {
                console.log('fail', response);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/vLUVa/1/

## JS:-

```
$('#draggable li').draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
    }
});

var user_id="temp";

$('#droppable').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // How to get the id from draggable here so the correct list item is acted on?
        $('#draggable li').remove();
        var id=$(ui.helper).attr("id").split("_");
        id=id[1];
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                'id': id,
                    'user_id': user_id // user_id comes from PHP
            } // end ajax        }
        });
    }
});
```

## HTML:-

```
<ul id="draggable">
    <li id="list_1">List item 1</li>
    <li id="list_2">List item 2</li>
    <li id="list_3">List item 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="droppable" style="height:300px;width:300px;background:green;"></div>
```